# Is there a consensus on what should be documented in the class and __init__ docstrings?

Tags: python, docstring, code-documentation

I did not find any best practice about what should be documented in the class and `__init__` docstrings. Sometimes I find that the constructor arguments are already documented in the class docstring, sometimes the are described in the `__init__` docstring. I prefer describing the construction within the class docstring, as this is what you call when creating a new instance. But what should be documented in the `__init__` methods docstring then?

---

*edit:*

I know about the [google styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) and the [google docstring style example](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html), but both do not answer my question. The docstring style example does say

> The `__init__` method may be documented in either the class level
> docstring, or as a docstring on the `__init__` method itself.
> Either form is acceptable, but the two should not be mixed. Choose one
> convention to document the `__init__` method and be consistent with it.

But if I choose to put the docstring of the `__init__` function into the class level docstring, what should the `__init__` docstring contain?

Comment: See also: [docstring in class or \_\_init\_\_ constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189661/docstring-in-class-or-init-constructor)

Answer (score 35):

There is an official answer, in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) (the docstring PEP), which is arguably authoritative:

> The class constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__` method.

This is quite logical, as this is the usual procedure for functions and methods, and `__init__()` is not an exception.

As a consequence, this puts the code and its documentation in the same place, which helps maintenance.

Finally, tools that display documentation to the user (like Jupyter, or the built-in Python shell command `help()`) are more likely to correctly display the documentation of your code. In practice, they *do* display the `__init__()` docstring automatically when you ask for help on the *class*, so this is one more reason to follow the official convention of putting the initialization documentation in `__init__()`.

Comment: Unfortunately an end-user would never find this documentation, since they'll type `help(MyClass)` not `help(MyClass.__init__)` when they get stuck.  So I personally think the PEP is not making the best suggestion, only following the rules.  It would make sense if the `help(MyClass)` docstring had a mechanism for including/displaying the __init__ docstring.

Comment: Fortunately, this comment is not correct: `help(MyClass)` shows all the methods of the class, and `__init__()` is one of them, so the user does have the information they need for creating objects. This is consistent with the official requirement. Furthermore, a tool like the Jupyter notebook does something similar when you ask for the arguments of a class constructor (with shift+tab): it displays both the class _and the init docstring_. The moral is  that following some common convention is very helpful—especially when it's a good one.

Comment: You are correct, the PEP suggestion is pretty good then.  I still don't like having to scroll to `__init__()` in the help output - again, this is a function the end user never sees, but is expected to know that it's invisibly remapped to the name of the class instead.  In terms of doc readability/obviousness this is kind of ugly, but that's just programming for you I guess. Thanks for the correction, i'll just write "see __init__()" in my class's docstring for noobs (of which I'll have many using my modules).

Comment: Both Jupyter (through `MyClass?`) and Python (through `help(MyClass)`) automatically display the init docstring, so this should be pretty obvious. Since it's a standard, it's likely that users will see this in many other libraries, too.

Comment: Interesting addition: Spyder automatically uses the contents of `ClassName.__doc__` for Tab-auto-completion when instancing the class, NOT the contents of `ClassName.__init__.__doc__`.  So this makes documenting in the *class* much more useful to the end-user.  Also as others said, NumpyDoc also says to document constructor in Class docstring. Lastly, `help(MyClass)` doesn't appear to put the `__init__` help at the top, making locating the constructor arguments irritating!

Comment: I would argue that both Spyder and NumpyDoc missed the fact that there is a convention, which has the non-desirable results that you observed. Personally I don't mind `help(MyClass)` putting the `__init__()` docstring at the bottom, since the command really asks for help on the class, and therefore information on what the class provides should come first. Whatever convention help-providing programs choose, the only way of getting a good and consistent behavior is for everybody to follow standards.

Comment: There needs to be a PythonStudio.

Answer (score 24):

The class documentation should include the **public** components of the object. The `__init__` parameters may or may not be public, so whether they are included in the class docstring or not depends on the object design.

The full paragraph in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) states:

> The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the
>   public methods and instance variables. If the class is intended to be
>   subclassed, and has an additional interface for subclasses, this
>   interface should be listed separately (in the docstring). The class
>   constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__`
>   method. Individual methods should be documented by their own
>   docstring.

And the [google style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) states:

> Classes should have a docstring below the class definition describing
>   the class. If your class has public attributes, they should be
>   documented here in an Attributes section and follow the same
>   formatting as a function’s Args section.

So the documentation determination hinges on whether the parameters for `__init__` are **public**. If the intention of the object is for users to construct their own instances, the `__init__` parameters should be documented in the class docstring. However, if an object is constructed internally then returned to the user, the class documentation should only refer to the public aspects of the object.

So the following example from google suggest that the `likes_spam` parameter from `__init__` is public:

```
class SampleClass(object):
    """Summary of class here.

    Longer class information....
    Longer class information....

    Attributes:
        likes_spam: A boolean indicating if we like SPAM or not.
        eggs: An integer count of the eggs we have laid.
    """

    def __init__(self, likes_spam=False):
        """Inits SampleClass with blah."""
        self.likes_spam = likes_spam
        self.eggs = 0

    def public_method(self):
        """Performs operation blah."""
```

However, below the public `likes_spam` attribute is determined during `__init__` based on two internal parameters `spam_count` and `like_threshold`. So, `likes_spam` is documented in the class docstring, while `spam_count` and `like_threshold` are documented in the `__init__` docstring.

```
class SampleClass(object):
    """Summary of class here.

    Longer class information....
    Longer class information....

    Attributes:
        likes_spam: A boolean indicating if we like SPAM or not.
        eggs: An integer count of the eggs we have laid.
    """

    def __init__(self, spam_count, like_threshold=1):
        """Inits SampleClass.

        Args:
            spam_count: The amount of SPAM consumed.
            like_threshold: The threshold consumed that indicates 
                whether we like SPAM.
        """
        self.likes_spam = spam_count > like_threshold
        self.eggs = 0

    def public_method(self):
        """Performs operation blah."""
```

Answer (score 15):

The actual usage of the class is initialized by a command like `SampleClass(args)`, and no user is ever going to type in `SampleClass.__init__(args)`, so
from an end-user perspective, when they are confused, they are much more likely to type

```
help(SampleClass)
```

instead of

```
help(SampleClass.__init__)
```

So I think it makes sense to put all documentation into `SampleClass`'s docstring.
And in `__init__`'s docstring put *"Please see `help(SampleClass)` for more info"* just in case there's the off chance that someone (or some program) looks at it.

Comment: A user pointed out that `help(SampleClass)` does ALSO print out the help for `SampleClass.__init__()`, but unfortunately Spyder shows this line *at the Bottom of the list of methods*. In theory documenting constructor in `init__()` would be adequate, except still confusing since again the user never sees the term `__init__` and must know that this is invisibly remapped to `MyClass(args)`). In this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019744/is-there-a-consensus-what-should-be-documented-in-the-classes-and-init-docst/57926574?noredirect=1#comment102775909_57926574

Answer (score 9):

I personally try to use the [google styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) when possible

When you create a new instance with `__init__` it should be documented what member variables are initialized. Then other people know what they can expect when they need to access them later in their code.

Sample from the google styleguide:

```py
class SampleClass(object):
    """Summary of class here.

    Longer class information....
    Longer class information....

    Attributes:
        likes_spam: A boolean indicating if we like SPAM or not.
        eggs: An integer count of the eggs we have laid.
    """

    def __init__(self, likes_spam=False):
        """Inits SampleClass with blah."""
        self.likes_spam = likes_spam
        self.eggs = 0

    def public_method(self):
        """Performs operation blah."""
```

Comment: I try to use that guid, too, but it does not answer my question, as I stated in my updated question.

Comment: imho you should document what member (which are not "private") variables are initialized. Then other people know what they can expect when they access them

Comment: valid point, but this answer has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 8):

NumpyDoc [Style Guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#class-docstring) says you should document the `__init__` in the class document and that the arguments of `__init__` should be listed in a Parameters section.

> The constructor (__init__) should also be documented here, the Parameters section of the docstring details the constructor’s parameters.

Here are examples from numpy's code base where you can see where `__init__` doesn't have a docstring. Instead it shows up in the class document.

- [class iinfo @getlimits.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9815c16f449e12915ef35a8255329ba26dacd5c0/numpy/core/getlimits.py#L631)
- [class format_parser @records.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9815c16f449e12915ef35a8255329ba26dacd5c0/numpy/core/records.py#L88)
- [class _Parse @ccompiler_opt.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9815c16f449e12915ef35a8255329ba26dacd5c0/numpy/distutils/ccompiler_opt.py#L1711)

As pandas also [follows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_docstring.html) Numpy Doc style, one can spot examples from pandas, too:

- [class DataFrame @frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bdc79c146c2e32f2cab629be240f01658cfb6cc2/pandas/core/frame.py#L509)
- [class GroupBy @groupby.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bdc79c146c2e32f2cab629be240f01658cfb6cc2/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1225)

Comment: This goes against the official guideline from PEP 257.

Comment: Spyder then also goes against the official guideline then, as it seems that Spyder gets it's tab-autocompletion text from the *class*, not the *__init__*.

Comment: I guess we should ask the question "*Why are major packages with an enormous userbase doing this differently from PEP 257 guidelines.*" I have seen SO users refer to numpy/numpydoc as "standards". Maybe there is a good reason.  Are there other packages which also don't follow PEP 257?

Comment: @Demis Spyder does something weird for me. If I press Ctrl+I, it gets the class docstring. If I use `function?` it shows the class and then the `__call__` docstring, but if I type `function(` it shows a popup that starts in the middle of the `Returns` section of the class docstring...

Comment: This other question got some answers pointing out that Sphinx parses the docstring,  I still don’t really understand how it does that. 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25144896

Comment: Btw. You can find examples quite easily with regex `^class[\S\s\n]{0,400}Parameters` (400 is max. characters between "class" and "Parameters". Adjust if needed.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any consensus on that point.

However, the [sphinx autodoc](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#auto-directives) module allows documentation to be generated from your *docstring*.Therefore it tends to enforce consistent *docstring* documentation.

In your case, I would document what the `class` is **and** the constructor arguments in the `class` *docstring* like:

```
class MyClass:
    """I am a class.
    I do funny stuff

    :type tags: dict
    :param tags: A dictionary of key-value pairs
    """

    def __init__(tags):
        self.tags = tags
```

Comment: Like I said, that's what I would prefere, too. But as most guides encourage you to also write docstrings for special functions, I wonder what the `__init__` docstring should contain, as all it should do is initialize a class instance. Also, with tools like sphinx, information written in the docstring of special functions won't show in the built documentation, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Well, as there is no consensus on that matter and as far as I know no official python documentation tackles it. I would tend to say, do as you think suits the best to your need.
I think the real question here is why do you want to add docstring to special functions then (for what purpose)? I mean in which context? Is it for documenting the code, to generate docs?

Answer (score 0):

Google has their own style guide for Python, which is not a bad thing to refer to.  Here is a link with what they consider best practices for doc-strings:  http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html

Comment: They don't answer my question, as I stated in my updated question.

Comment: From your updated question: "But if I choose to put the docstring of the __init__ function into the class level docstring, what should the __init__ docstring contain?"

Based on the style guide, in that case, your __init__ method should not have a docstring.