# docstring in class or __init__ constructor?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

There seem to be two places where you can put docstrings for a class:

1. Right under the class definition:

   ```
   class MyClass:
       """Summary of MyClass.

       Body.
       """
   ```
2. Right under the `__init__` constructor:

   ```
   class MyClass:
       def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
           """Summary of MyClass.

           Body.
           """
   ```

Which is preferred? Or is it okay to have both?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#specification

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They can both exist, since they are both intended for different things.

> **The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the public methods and instance variables.** If the class is intended to be subclassed, and has an additional interface for subclasses, this interface should be listed separately (in the docstring). **The class constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__` method.** Individual methods should be documented by their own docstring.

Emphasis mine.
This reference is from [**PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Comment: Also, for sphinx documentation I found there is an option to show both [class and `__init__` docstring by setting `autoclass_content = both`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599254/how-to-use-sphinxs-autodoc-to-document-a-classs-init-self-method)