# Python class constructor docstring with __new__ or metaclass

Tags: python, docstring, pep

[Previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019744/is-there-a-consensus-on-what-should-be-documented-in-the-class-and-init-docs) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189661/docstring-in-class-or-init-constructor) have asked whether to put the constructor docstring under the `class` definition or under `__init__`. The answer is given in [PEP 257 – Docstring Conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/):

> The class constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__` method.

However, both `__new__` and `metaclass`, as actual constructors, have the ability to modify the function signature before the arguments given to the constructor are passed on to the initializer `__init__`. Since PEP 257 said the constructor docstring should be written in `__init__`, should the docstring describe the arguments provided by the user when `my_var = MyClass(*args1, **kwargs1)` is called, or the arguments when `__init__(self, *args2, **kwargs2)` is invoked? It is not guaranteed that `args1 == args2`, `kwargs1 == kwargs2`. In general, how should the effects of `__new__` and `metaclass` be documented?